# MLOps Approach for Azure ML Designer Pipelines Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-ml-pipelines

We've been delving into the new Azure ML Designer and find it promising for initiating model training experiments. However, we're keen on incorporating MLOps to iteratively train models and deploy stable versions to higher environments.

We've checked the [MLOps v2 documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/ai-ml/guide/machine-learning-operations-v2) and have set up the starter pipelines in Azure DevOps as per the documentation. The [starter repository](https://github.com/Azure/mlops-v2-ado-demo) includes a Python-based experiment deployed as a model, which is then pushed to a higher environment. This serves as an excellent example for code-driven models.

However, we're curious about best practices or guidelines for applying the same MLOps approach to models built with the Azure ML Designer pipelines. Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you please help clarify whether you need help with the Azure DevOps pipeline or the Azure ML pipeline? It's suggested that you could describe your requirements in more detail. Thanks.

Comment: We are using Azure DevOps for training and deploying models with the MLOps approach and seeking help deploying models through Azure DevOps that are created with ML Designer pipelines. Hope it makes it clear?

Comment: You can check whether these docs are helpful for you. [Machine Learning DevOps (MLOps) with Azure ML](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/educator-developer-blog/machine-learning-devops-mlops-with-azure-ml/ba-p/742150). [Set up MLOps with Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-setup-mlops-azureml?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=azure-shell).

Comment: thank you for sharing the link, however they almost refer back to the same documentation links posted in the original question.